# How to open browser window in iframe using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want to open a application within iframe. I am using below script to do it. But, I am not able to open it within iframe.

Can someone help me to figure out how to open it in in `iframe`.

I have tried searching for the solution but could not find.

I have provided the complete JavaScript code in here.

I tried following code.

```
@{   
    string Url = ViewBag.Url;
    string Token = ViewBag.Token;
    string Response = ViewBag.Response;
}

<br />
<div id='signal'>
    <center><img src="~/images/gears.gif" /></center>   
</div>

<iframe src="@Url"></iframe>

<div id="output"></div>
<div id="divBackground"></div>
```

JavaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url'.replace(/amp;/g, ''),
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + '@Token');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var params = [
        'height=' + screen.height,
        'width=' + screen.width
      ].join(',');

      var popUp;

      function showModal() {
        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

        iframe.src = '@Url';

        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        //popUp = window.open("", "_blank", params);
        popUp.location.href = data.message;

        popUp.focus();
        LoadModal();
      }

      function LoadModal() {
        var bkg = document.getElementById("divBackground");
        bkg.style.display = "block";
      }

      function OnUnload() {
        if (false == popUp.closed) {
          popUp.close();
        }
      }

      window.onunload = OnUnload;

      showModal();
    },
    statusCode: {
      400: function() {
        alert("server returned a bad request response.");
      }
    },
    complete: function() {
      $("#signal").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you'll need an [<iframe>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to do anything in an `<iframe>` - currently that's what is lacking in your code

Comment: @Bravo, can you please show me an example. Thank you

Comment: of what? an iframe? creating one on code? `const iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); iframe.src="some url"; document.body.appendChild(iframe);`

Comment: @Bravo, so I don't need all the above code. If I do something like `const iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); iframe.src="@Url"; document.body.appendChild(iframe);` does it work? If possible then could you please provide me an answer. Thank you

Comment: I don't know - your code didn't use an iframe at all, so no idea

Comment: @Bravo, I have modified the script based on your code. But this is complaining about `{"message":"authorization header is required","statusCode":400,"error":true}`

Comment: based on my code? why? anyway, seems you can't do that since there's an authorization issue - is it your site? check what you did wrong

Comment: What are you "not able to do"?

Comment: @code, not able to open in iframe.